# How to remove Chrome policies?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, group-policy

I found some weird policies on my chrome by visiting chrome://policy/ (or about:policy), like *ExtensionInstallSources* or *ExtensionInstallWhitelist*. I though it may be from some virus because on other machines with a clean chrome install the policies are empty.

i went to the win 7 registry and removed all the keys/entries that contained the policies names, but when I visit chrome://policy/ they still show up.

I even tried removing the entire **\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\** folder and the unknown extensions I had disappeared but the policies still show up.

**How do I remove them?**

Comment: Someone told me to open gpedit.msc and search for google policies there, but I don't have any chrome under Administrative Templates

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a virus?

Comment: If you ended here but you have a Mac, run `defaults delete com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallWhitelist` in the Terminal.app

Answer (score 11):

Policies in Chrome are in the registry.
Is this your company computer? because if you removed it they will put it back again.
Anyway, delete the following keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google
```

Comment: Already removed them, but when I run chrome and visit chrome://policy, they are still there. It's a personal computer, connected to a home network, is the only pc in the network with this problem.

Comment: They could be keep coming from one of the extensions installed. Try to remove all the extensions one by one and see which one generate the policy.

Comment: for macOS, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/311435/118414

Answer (score 3):

i can't understand your problem, the windows registry locations of chrome policies

**Windows registry location:**

```
Software\Policies\Chromium\ExtensionInstallWhitelist 
Software\Policies\Chromium\ExtensionInstallSources
```

for more information about all chrome policies go to http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3

Comment: Already removed them, but when I run chrome and visit chrome://policy, they are still there.

Answer (score 2):

To completely remove the policy, you need to do the following:

1. Delete the following Windows Registry keys:

   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google`
   - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google`
2. Uninstall Google Chrome
3. Delete the contents of following folder: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome`
4. Delete the contents of following folder: `%WINDIR%\System32\GroupPolicy`
5. Delete the contents of following folder: `%WINDIR%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers`
6. Open the command prompt and run the following command: `gpupdate /force`
7. Install Google Chrome

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution and this ill work in mac to remove them to remove chrome policies on mac.
First Go to the finder.
then go to  */Library/Managed Preferences/[user]/*

com.google.Chrome.plist
complete.plist

Remove these files and done.
Please do response if it is helpful or not.
Thank you